# How to start a graphical utility from command line

Tags: command-line

In my machine I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed putty. I want to start putty  from command line. When I run the program from command line and after closing the terminal, putty also gets terminated. How to avoid that ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add an "&" behind your command. So putty& will be your command, this will tell the terminal to run it in background. Next you have to type "disown" to detach the process from the terminal.

so:

```
user@yourhost:putty&
user@yourhost:disown
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the command with `nohoup`:

```
nohup putty &
exit
```

Comment: I thing appending `&` is quite enough. `nohup` detaches the process from the user so it still runs when the user logs out. right?

Comment: No `nohup` prevents its child process from receiving incoming HUP signals. This will let `putty` keep running after the "command line" the OP mentioned, is closed.